# Calling Python script in C# program

Tags: c#, python-2.7

I know that there are lots of samples on this on the net.  But all of which is not working to me.

Say I have a .py file that does image processing.  It saved an image to its current location. Say in "C:\src\Image Processing\saved.image"

In my c# code, I have this one, as browsed in google,

```
    private void run_cmd(string cmd, string args)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
        start.FileName = "C:/Python27/Python.exe";
        start.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1}", cmd, args);
        start.UseShellExecute = false;
        start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
            {
                string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                Console.Write(result);
            }
        }
    }
```

---

```
    private void SimulateBn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        run_cmd("EdgeDetection.py", "C:/src/Image Processing");
    }
```

---

The codes above does NOT generate any error but the script is supposedly generate an image but it did NOT generate any.

Please help.

Comment: You need to put the args part in start.Arguments in double quotes as the pathname contains spaces.

Comment: you mean like this? run_cmd("EdgeDetection.py", "\"C:/src/Image Processing/EdgeDetection.py\"");

Comment: It doesn't work still :(

Comment: Also, you probably need to specify an explicit path to EdgeDetection.py. And, not sure, but Windows uses backslashes \ rather than forward slashes in pathnames.

Comment: I also tried that one as well. but with no luck at all

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas, sorry. I was able to run an identical program successfully by quoting the arguments and specifying an explicit path to the program. (Disregard my comment about the slashes - Windows, or .NET, appears to handle both variants without issues.)